# CSS 2 DIVs in 2 Polygons overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have created 2 Divs with CSS polygon function to be 2 triangles and build a div together. Both triangles have theyr own divs inside. When i resize the screen, i want the first upper-div overflowing the second triangle.

```
<div class="boxes">
<div class="box box1">
    <div class="info left">gute Entscheidung</div>
</div>
<div class="box box2">
    <div class="info right">schlechte Entscheidung</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/46vcbw2x/5/ where the green div should be above the yellow triangle.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make easier if you consider background instead of `clip-path` because `clip-path` will clip all the content inside and you cannot make the green div outside:

```css
.boxes {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,blue 49%,yellow 50%);
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  display:inline-block;
  background: green;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="info left">gute Entscheidung</div>
  <div class="info right">schlechte Entscheidung</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am doing a tutorial but your approach is much easier, thanks :D